# Unit testing speed of network in Android

Tags: android, benchmarking

I want to test which method is faster. I use DefaultHttpClient and one method is implemented in Apache HttpClient and the other one is in HttpUrlClient which is recommended for Android. Both methods do the same and I want to test which one is more efficient.

I am not very familiar with unit testing, can someone give me some advice on how should I test the time?

Comment: This is not unit testing. You should rephrase your question and re-tag it

Answer (score 1):

To test this kind of thing you want to have the whole stack, so not a pure unit test. I would suggest running it on a real device and making a test that does a large number of requests (couple 100 or 1000), maybe retrieve the data from it and measure the time spent.

```
long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
  doStuff();
}
System.out.println("Took "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start)+"ms");
```

Comment: That was my idea, the problem is that I don't know how to write such a test